# How can I find the path of iOS app internal directory in Swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

How can I find the path of iOS app internal directory in Swift?

Firstly, what is the equivalent name of android app internal directory in iOS app?

Secondly, how can I find the path of the directory? 
which api should I use in Swift?

My main purpose is trying to copy Bundle sqlite file to the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get path of document directory you can use this code.

```
 // path to documents directory
let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
if let documentDirectoryPath = documentDirectoryPath { 

}
```

For more information follow these links : [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) and  [Accessing Files and Directories](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public func getDatabasePath() -> String {

    let databaseURL = try? FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("YOUR_DB_FILE_NAME.sqlite")

    // If DB file not present in file manager copy DB file to user document directory
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if  fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (databaseURL?.path)!) {
        print("FILE AVAILABLE")
        return (databaseURL?.path)!
    } else {
        print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE ... Copying")
        if fileManager.createFile(atPath: (databaseURL?.path)!, contents: Data(), attributes: nil) {
            return (databaseURL?.path)!
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```